How to Duplicate a SwiftData object
I have a SwiftData model called Workout that contains a array of Exercise Model which itself contains an array of Sets Model,
Before I had a copy method in these models for creating a new object from the properties of old objects and it worked correctly, but since introducing Relationships between these models whenever I try to call the copy method of Exercise I get the error message:

Fatal error: Unsupported relationship key path ReferenceWritableKeyPath<MySet, Exercise>

This are the copy methods:
@Model
class Workout: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Exercise.workout) //when deleting a workout you delete all exericses that happened during that workout
    var exercises: [Exercise]?
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date
    
    func copy() -> Workout {
        let workout = Workout(id: UUID(), name: name, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)
          workout.name = name
          workout.startTime = Date.now
          workout.endTime = Date.now
          workout.exercises = exercises?.map { $0.copy() }
          return workout
      }
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String = "", startTime: Date = Date.now, endTime: Date = Date.now) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = endTime
    }
    
    

}



@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var exerciseName: ExerciseName
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \MySet.exercise)
    var sets: [MySet]?    //When an Exercise gets Deleted all Sets associated need to get deleted

    var date: Date
    var workout: Workout
 
    func copy() -> Exercise {
        let newExercise = Exercise(id: UUID(), exerciseName: exerciseName, date: Date.now, workout: workout)
        
        // Copy the related sets
        if let existingSets = sets {
            newExercise.sets = existingSets.map { set in
                // Copy each set and associate it with the newExercise
                let newSet = set.copy(exercise: newExercise)
                return newSet
            }
        }
        
        return newExercise
    }
    
    init(id: UUID, exerciseName: ExerciseName, date: Date, workout: Workout) {
        self.id = id
        self.exerciseName = exerciseName
        self.date = date
        self.workout = workout
    }

    
}


@Model
class MySet: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
 
    var exercise: Exercise
    
    var date: Date
    
    //make a copy functionality so you can call this and pass it an Exercise when copying a Set
    func copy(exercise: Exercise) -> MySet {
        MySet(id: UUID(), weight: weight, reps: reps, isCompleted: isCompleted,date: Date.now , exercise: exercise)
        }
    
    init(
        id: UUID,
        weight: Int,
        reps: Int,
        isCompleted: Bool,
        date: Date,
        exercise: Exercise
        
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.reps = reps
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
        self.date = date
        self.exercise = exercise
      
    }
    

    
}

Xcode says the error occurs in the set method of var sets: [MySet]?
why did these copy methods work before introducing an inverse relationships between these models and not now?

According to this answer here, you cannot set a relationship without using modelContext. So we need two things to do

Using ModelContext
Creating new entities for this copy function

Here is the code example (I hope it works):
func copy() -> Exercise {
let newExercise = Exercise(id: UUID(), exerciseName: exerciseName, date: Date(), workout: workout)
context.insert(newExercise)
    // Copy each set and associate it with the new exercise
if let _sets = sets {
    newExercise.sets = _sets.map { set in
        let newSet = MySet(id: UUID(), weight: set.weight, reps: set.reps, isCompleted: set.isCompleted, date: Date.now, exercise: newExercise)
        
        // Insert the newSet into the model context
        context.insert(newSet)
        
        return newSet
    }
}

return newExercise
}

